What are the verses that suggest Sri Krishna is the Supreme Personality?
As preached by the followers of Nimbarka Sampradaya & Brahma-Madhava-Gaudiya Sampradaya followers, Krishna is the Supreme Personality.
One verse that they refer is the ŚB 1.3.28:

एते चांशकला: पुंस: कृष्णस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् । इन्द्रारिव्याकुलं लोकं मृडयन्ति युगे युगे ॥ २८ ॥

Another one is from Gopala-tapani Upanishad 1.24

yo brahmanam vidadhati purvam yo vai vedams ca gapayati sma krsnah

What are other verses which suggest the same thing?
